# How to get a destructured result from a fetch call inside a function, to be called in another function

Tags: javascript, function, destructuring

I'm testing destructuring of results fetched from an api. How do I call some of the data in a separate function

I fetched some data from this api `https://randomuser.me/api/` in a function and destructured the results.
And I am trying to get some data from the destructured result inside another function.

This is what i've managed so far:

```
let mail = () => { 
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(responseJson) {
        // i destructured to get out the 'results' inside the response
        let {results} = responseJson;
        // i'm using just the first object in the result (the result is an array)
        // hence this second destructuring
        let [profile] = [results[0]];

        // i can get log out the email when i call the function
        console.log('user mail: ', profile.email);
      });
}
mail(); // logs the current random email
```

Now instead of logging out that email, I want it in a div on button click

```
// html
<div id="mail"></div>
<button onclick="getMail()"></button>
```

```
// the onclick script
const getMail = ({email}) => {
    // this is where i'm stuck
    // i'm trying to get the email here 

    document.querySelector('#mail').innerHTML = `current email: ${email}`
}
```

Comment: It's an *asynchronous* operation. You can't use a simple `return` to get the value.

Comment: Also `let profile = results[0];` is a little simpler.

Comment: That makes sense, I tried using `return` it doesn't return anything